# How to unit test a bootstrap modal close function in jasmine - Angular8

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method in one of the ts file in which it will hide the bootstrap modal. This method has parameter which actually the modal instance and using the jQuery hide() method Im hiding the modal popup.

```
modalClose(modal: ModalCompoment) {
   this.open = false;
   modal.modalInstance.getModalInstance().hide();
 }
```

modal.component.ts code

```
export class ModalDialogComponent implements Oninit { 
  @input() modalId = 'modal-dialog';
  @Input() title = '';
  @ContentChild('modalHead', {static: false}) headerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;; false
  @ViewChild('modalInstance', {static}) modalInstance: ElementRef;
 
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}

   getModalInsatnce : any{
     const modal = Object. 
     getOwnPropertyNames(this.modalInsatnce. nativeElement). 
     filter(n 
       => n.startsWith('jquery')). map(n=> this.modalInsatnce. 
      nativeElement[n]['bs.modal']). find(j=> j!== undefined);
     return modal;
      }
     }
  }
```

Spec file code

```
it('test modal' () => {
 let modalComp : ModalComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalComponent>;
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(modalComp);
 modalComp = fixture. componentInsatnce;
 component.modalClose(modalComp);
 expect(component.open).toEqual(false);
 // need to cover hide() code line
});
```

With this code Im getting error: Cannot read property nativeElement of undefined. I need to cover the unit test for line modal.modalInstance.getModalInstance().hide();. Request anyone to help in this issue.

Comment: Please share the test that you have written so far, so that we can suggest improvements in the same.

Comment: I was not able to pass the modal instance as event in the spec file.

Comment: I would like to see the event object that you have passed in your test while calling the modalClose method

Comment: Do you only intend to test / assert that the hide() method of the modalInstance was called ?

Comment: Yes. How to pass the getModalInsatnce and hide here.

Comment: Try something like this 

````
const event = {

 modalInstance : {
  getModalInstance : () => {
   hide: () => null 
  }
 } as any;
} as any; ````

Comment: Sorry about the bad indent, I'll post this as an answer, once we are sure it works for you :)

Comment: This is not working. I have edited the question. Now Im passing the modal component as parameter here.

Comment: Could you please tell me what error are you facing with the above solution ?  If you can please paste your test, that'd be great

Comment: Ive updated the code and jasmine tests. Pls let me know what i did wrong.

Comment: @AkshAyAgrawal: I've updated the code. Do we have any solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't see my suggestion incorporated in your update.  You need to use mock objects in your test. Before passing modalComp to component.modalClose(modalComp), you need to do this modal.modalInstance = { getModalInstance : () => { hide: () => null } } as any;